# How can I set a hidden input value by class in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table structure.

```
<table id="my_table">
 <tr class="odd" id="row_1">
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_1" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" id="row_2">
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_2" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" id="row_3">
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_3" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="even" id="row_4">
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_4" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="even" id="row_5">
 <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_5" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="even" id="row_6">
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="flight_6" value=""></td>
 </tr>
```

How can I set the value of the hidden value for each row based on the class of the tr tags. For instance I have 9 row in the table with class 'odd' for 3 rows, 'even' for the next 3 rows and 'odd' for the last 3 rows. This can be dynamic, as in I could have 5 classes of rows alternating back and forth in the table creating 7 rows with class 'even', 7 rows  with class 'odd' and back to 'even' etc. What I need to do is set the hidden values for each class to end up being '1' for the first 'odd' class and then '2' for the next 'even' class etc. I have tried to no avail using jquery. My jquery skills are pretty limited. Is this possible using jquery or is there another solutuion?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current class equals the previous class, and increment a counter

```
var i = 0;

$('#my_table tr').each(function() {
    if ( this.className != ($(this).prev().length ? $(this).prev().get(0).className : '')) i++;
    $(this).find('input').val(i);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ny5W/1/)

Comment: This input type is hidden and based on an id not a text input.

Comment: @user3287677 - How does that matter? I made the inputs visible to see the result, it works exactly the same with hidden inputs, and how is the ID relevant at all ?